# transform List<Staging<Importable>> to List<Staging<ImportableImpl>> with java 8 stream

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have an interface called `Importable` which has multiple implementations and one of them is `ImportableImpl`.

I have a list of a class `Staging` which has a generic type: `Importable`.

Via java 8 stream, I would like to transform the list:

```
List<Staging<Importable>> list1
```

to a list:

```
List<Staging<ImportableImpl>> list2
```

I am already sure that the list `list1` is a list of `Staging<ImportableImpl>`, so no `ClassCastException` can occurs.
I don't know if java authorizes this kind of transformation with generics type.

I wanted to try something like this:

```
list1.stream()
   .map(Staging::getImportable) // retrieve generic type
   .map(ImportableImpl.class::cast)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But with this I will get a `List<ImportableImpl>` and not a `List<Staging<ImportableImpl>>`.

Comment: How do you create a `Staging` object?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Perhaps you should add more methods to your interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't realise what the purpose of your attempts, but you are not allowed to turn a `List<Staging<Importable>>` to a `List<Staging<ImportableImpl>>` regardless of whatever is in the first list. These types are inconvertible.

The only reasonable way to do that (with a warning, though) is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // if you are sure that all elements are ImportableImpl
list.stream().map(i -> (Staging<ImportableImpl>) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where the `list` has a type of `List<Staging<? extends Importable>>`, not a `List<Staging<Importable>>`.

---

Of course, it can be written with a method reference:

```
list.stream().map(Staging.class::<ImportableImpl>cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you've got to create a new staging object...

This answer assumes you can create a `Staging` object by using `new Staging<>(thing)`. Is this what you need?

```
list1.stream()
   .map(s -> new Staging<ImportableImpl>(s.getImportable()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This is the solution I chose but I wanted to know if there was way to do it without creating a new object. All the other fields of Staging have to be set again with this solution.

Comment: @louisamoros if you are certain that the Staging objects contain `ImportableImpl`s, you could do an unsafe cast, for example `.map(s -> (Staging<ImportableImpl>) ((Staging) s)))`

Comment: @louisamoros I agree with some of the other comments though, this is a bit of a nasty thing to do

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right than you basically just want to express that your `list1` actually already is a List of type `List<Staging<ImportableImpl>>`. Thus throwing away the abstraction provided by your interface `Importable`.

As at runtime none of the Generic types exist you should be able to just cast `List<Staging<ImportableImpl>> list2 = (List) list1`. This is an unchecked cast (usung the raw form as an intermediate) and will remove some of the safety the type system provides. It might break if someone added an object of type `Staging<AnotherImportableImpl>` to `list1`.
Using fancy constructs like streams does not change the situation. Basically you just want to tell the compiler that you're sure you know something it cannot check.